# Reading Linux kernel documentation in terminal

Tags: linux-kernel, documentation

Is there a way to read `Linux Kernel` documentation offline in the terminal? For exmple, I am reading this document online: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt

If I use Linux system, shouldn't the system already have one document copy. How can I access them in terminal?

Comment: Linux is not an OS. Gnu/Linux is, but even then there are multiple distributions. So one distribution may have the documents installed by default, another may allow you to install them, and yet a third may provide no mechanism to install them, but you could install them manually in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `curl` something like:

```
curl https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt | less
```

The command `curl` can visualize the document `cgroups.txt` in the same format as in the original webpage. You could pipe the output to the command `less` to be able to scroll through the text.

[image]

Comment: What I want is like: `man cgroup`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express my idea clearly. I updated the problem. Does the kernel document have one copy local? If so, how to access the documents like `man cgroup`?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please amend question, by amending question. Having to read all comments, to understand the question, will result in misunderstandings, reduce quality of answers, and delay answers. (any you won't have to say it twice)

Comment: Dear Joe, according to your question. l understood that you would like to visualize the kernel documents using Terminal. You can run the command `curl` as I had provided. It will show the document exactly similar to `cgroups.txt` document and in the same format. Pipe the command to the command  `less` to be able to scroll through the document. Please let me know if this is what you want ;-)

Comment: Your distribution (Debian, Ubuntu, Centos) may offer a local copy; please edit your question to include the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Linux sources downloaded, the same documentation (for the downloaded version) is available in `doc/` subfolder.

You can download online files with `wget`, e.g. `wget https://...`.

A simple way to read text files is to use a pager such as `less`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express my idea clearly. I updated the problem. Does the kernel document have one copy local? If so, how to access the documents like `man cgroup`?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please amend question, by amending question. Having to read all comments, to understand the question, will result in misunderstandings, reduce quality of answers, and delay answers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to view this

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

in the terminal on Debian.

Install kernel specific docs

`apt install linux-doc`

Locate the file of interest

`dpkg -L linux-doc | grep sysctl`

View it

`less /usr/share/doc/linux-doc/sysctl/vm.txt.gz`